# How to solve the ValueError in DNN(Deep Neural Network) Model using python?

Tags: python, pandas, keras, deep-learning, dotnetnuke

I'm new to DNN(Deep Neural Network) model.
I have a CSV file to train the data, but I got some problems.
The following picture is my data:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OhOk.jpg)

I tried to make the dataset to feature and label, but I got some problems.
The following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import datasets, preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

#read file
input_file = 'Balanced_Data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(input_file,encoding='utf-8')

# set label and features
hkgf_labels = np.array(df['政治傾向']) 
hkgf_features = df[['時間區間','政治傾向']] 


trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(hkgf_features, hkgf_labels, test_size = 0.3)
trainY = trainY.reshape(-1, 1)
testY = testY.reshape(-1, 1)

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1), metrics=['mse','mape'])

# fit model
dnn = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=20, batch_size=30)

# predict
y_predict = model.predict(testX)
y_predict_1 = model.predict(trainX)

# mse
np.mean(np.abs((testY-y_predict)))
# mape
np.mean(np.abs((testY-y_predict) / testY)) * 100
```

When I execute `dnn = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=20, batch_size=30)`, I got the following problem:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:754 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:255 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape (None, 2)
```

I tried to find some simular solution from `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3 but received input with shape (None, 2)`, but I cannont to solve my problem.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!!

Comment: Why did you set input_dim=3? It seems your data has 2 dimensions, not 3.

Comment: Oh~~ I see~~ If I have 50 features, I should set input_dim=50 ? Thanks